# i have an authentication device with built in php 5.1 i dont have access to change php.ini or default.ph

Tags: javascript, php, curl

```
$opts = array('http' => array('timeout' => 36000) ); 
request_terminate_timeout = 3600s; 
$context = stream_context_create($opts); 
$url = "https://www.innkeyapp.com/SerRest.svc/GetOccupiedRoomData?sharedkey=2diSq8bjZ4N3ZR4XB5K+LXxSlBxuQ37IrkvUmVtHe3s=&roomno=311"; 
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context); 

var_dump($result); 

die();
```

or

```
$res1= file_get_contents("https://www.innkeyapp.com/SerRest.svc/GetOccupiedRoomData?sharedkey=2diSq8bjZ4N3ZR4XB5K+LXxSlBxuQ37IrkvUmVtHe3s=&roomno=311"); 

echo $res1;
```

i am getting

> connection reset by peer client or failed to open stream

Comment: This is __unreadable__. [edit] your question.

Comment: You should also probably remove the shared key.

Comment: Is inkeyapp.com your own domain? If not do you  know what SerRest.svc does (did you write SerRest, if not the script maybe resetting/cacelling the request)?

Comment: There is names and contact numbers displayed when the links are followed I hope it is not customer data from a production system.

Comment: yes it is...... i am soory ,lacking

Answer (score 0):

The url you are trying to access could be blocking your request since it does not have user-agent header. Your request might be considered as unsafe.

You can try to pass additional http headers such as the user-agent header. For example:

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
              "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/64.0.3282.167 Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36"
  )
);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php for more information on creating streams

Comment: its coming boolean(false)